# Remove submodule repository from Xcode source control

Tags: xcode, git

I had 2 submodules which I deleted recently. Removed them from `.gitmodules`, removed them from project directory, removed them from `.git/modules`. But Xcode still thinks that they're existing in Source Control. So I noticed an `xccheckout` file that contains the remotes. I googled about half of hour how to actually remove them, and found a single f...g instruction to remove them manually from `xccheckout`, others are about how to remove Git support from project (which isn't actually what I f...g need) or questions about should I put `xccheckout` into `.gitignore` or not.

Am I doing something wrong? Isn't there any way to remove the submodule link from Xcode project with actually the program created it? Am I the only who needs this?

Comment: Once you removed the gitlink (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26751272/6309), did you try to clone your own repo, and see if XCode still sees submodules in that new clone?