# Xcode 6 how to remove branch in origin

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode6, azure-devops

I have two question about Xcode 6 by operational git version control.

1.
I created a branch xxx and push this branch to server ,but I don't want it anymore, can I remove it.
When I selected origin branch (Test01,Test02) , I couldn't click remove sign "-".
If selected local branch it can click remove sign "-".
[image]

2.
Does any way to checkout old version from server in Xcode 6?
I using Visual Studio Team Services git version control

thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

If XCode doesn't allow that operation, you can at least fall back to the git command line and:
[delete the remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/6309) (and clean the remote traking branch in your repo)

```
    git push --delete 
    git fetch <remote> --prune
```